# Music stops after the review page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working on windows phone.

I have a page with a MediaElement playing a mp3 file. I used MarketPlaceReviewTask for in app review. When the review task is complete, the MediaElement stops playing the music file.

My question is how can I resume the music playback after the MarketPlaceReview task is complete. I tried using the GotFocus event of the page, didn't work. I am not sure about which event would be called in this case.

Comment: use `Application_Activated` event